# Add text from user input to hyperlink

Tags: html

Firstly I have very little knowlegde on web dev.

I want to a textbox on a website where the user enters a number. In this case 26

[image]

When the user clicks the Send button I want to open a new URL link that is ".000webhostapp.com/aboutme.html/26"

The last parameter will be the number entered. The reason why I want this is by the user clicking on Send it will open up an android app and passes the second parameter to the app. The app part is working perfectly. I just need to know how to do the HTML part now.

Can any one assist

My first attempt at web dev:

```
<HTML>

<head>
<title>Hello, CLAIM YOUR R3000! </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html/1234">DEEP LINK</li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<h1>Department</h1>
<p>D</p>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/cmtv1kO.png" alt="Space Doggo and the moon">
<h3>Frist to sign up!</h3>

<h2>Leave your awesome comment</h2>
<form>
    <input placeholder="Your number" type="text" id="num" name="number">
    
</form>
<a href="aboutme.html/num"><button>Send</button></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap your submit button with the `a` tag and create `eventListeners` instead so you can use the input as a parameter.

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Hello, CLAIM YOUR R3000! </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="aboutme.html/1234">DEEP LINK</li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Department</h1>
  <p>D</p>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cmtv1kO.png" alt="Space Doggo and the moon">
  <h3>Frist to sign up!</h3>

  <h2>Leave your awesome comment</h2>
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Your number" type="text" id="num" name="number">

  </form>
  <button class="submit">Send</button>
</body>

<script>
  function goToURL() {
    let number = document.getElementById("num").value;
    let url = 'aboutme.html/num' + number;

    window.open(url);
  }

  document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("click", goToURL);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Gee wiz that's by far the most direct and to the point answer...

Answer (score 1):

*My answer will be close to what others have already said while I was redacting it, but I hope to bring more insight on how this works.*

First of all, if you want to learn about web dev, go to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials).

You could almost use a regular HTML form here, but it would actually navigate to `.000webhostapp.com/aboutme.html/?number=26`. It's exactly the case with the one I've written below there. If you can adapt your server-side, it might be your best option.

Now if you really need to navigate to `.000webhostapp.com/aboutme.html/26`, then you will need to somehow rig the URL using Javascript. See detailed example below.

Also, there are a number of improvements you can do using HTML [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and the correct `<input>` type, which is `number` for your purpose. Implemented there as well.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _e => { //Exec script when HTML is loaded and parsed

  const frm = document.querySelector('#num-form');
  
  frm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    //Prevent the form from being actually submitted
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //Read input
    let val = frm.number.value;
    //Form has validation, but we never trust user input
    if (!val && val !== '0') {             //No value: quit
      return;
    }
    val = parseInt(val);                   //Will fail if value is not a number, which is good!
    
    let url = frm.getAttribute('action'); //Get the URL from HTML: easier to edit, closer to standards
    url += val;                           //Append number
    console.log("navigating to", url);
    //window.location.href = url; // <-- uncomment this to really navigate to url
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello, CLAIM YOUR R3000! </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- commenting out irrelevant parts
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="aboutme.html/1234">DEEP LINK</li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Department</h1>
  <p>D</p>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cmtv1kO.png" alt="Space Doggo and the moon">
  
  -->
  
  <h3>First to sign up!</h3>

  <h2>Leave your awesome comment</h2>
  <form action=".000webhostapp.com/aboutme.html/" id="num-form">
    <input placeholder="Your number" type="number" min="0" max="9999" name="number" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Javascript to handle to form submit event and use window.open to append the number after the "/" in url.

Use: `window.open("./aboutme.html/" + document.getElementById("num").value,` **"_blank"**`);`

to open a new tab in the browser.

```js
document.getElementById("YourForm").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open("./aboutme.html/" + document.getElementById("num").value);
})
```

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Hello, CLAIM YOUR R3000! </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="aboutme.html/1234">DEEP LINK</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Department</h1>
  <p>D</p>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cmtv1kO.png" alt="Space Doggo and the moon">
  <h3>Frist to sign up!</h3>

  <h2>Leave your awesome comment</h2>
  <form id="YourForm">
    <input placeholder="Your number" type="text" id="num" name="number">
    <button type="submit">
    Send
    </button>
  </form>

</body>

</HTML>
```